# What can we get via taking quotient of $\mathbb{C}P^1$ by a finite abelian group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, quotient-spaces, covering-spaces, projective-space

Let $G_n = \langle\tau\rangle$ and $G_m = \langle\sigma\rangle$ be groups of $n$-th and $m$-th roots of unity. Define action of $G_n \times G_m$ on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ as follows. $$ (\tau^k, \sigma^t) \cdot[x_0, x_1] = [\tau^kx_0, \sigma^tx_1]$$

I know that the only group that can act freely on sphere is $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ so I almost certainly won't get $\mathbb{R}P^2$. People say something about branched coverings and Riemann surfaces claiming there always will be $S^2$ but I don't have this machinery. What I do have is the first half of Hatcher's algebraic topology technical tools. What can I do to prove it's a sphere?

Comment: I would look at it very concretely: try to identify exactly what the orbits are so that you can draw a picture of the quotient.  You might start with the case $n=2,m=1$, say.

Comment: (Really, this question has nothing whatsoever to do with anything in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.  It's just about understanding what this quotient is very explicitly so you can write down an explicit homeomorphism.)

Comment: @Eric Wofsey it's the first case I tried and it looks like it is almost glueing together antipodal points but except one.

Comment: except two, I mean, zero and infinity